# Find next sibling an particular element in Selenium, Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I need the sibling of a previously selected element(s).

For example:

```
<div class="dt">Technology</div>
<div class="da">GSM / CDMA / HSPA / EVDO / LTE</div>
<div class="dt">Dimensions</div>
<div class="da">149.9 x 70.4 x 7.8 mm (5.90 x 2.77 x 0.31 in)</div>
<div class="dt">Weight</div>
<div class="da">157 g (5.54 oz)</div>
<div class="dt">Build</div>
<div class="da">Back glass (Gorilla Glass 5), aluminum frame    </div>
<div class="dt">Type</div>
<div class="da">Dynamic AMOLED capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors</div>
<div class="dt">SIM</div>
<div class="da">Single SIM (Nano-SIM) or Hybrid Dual SIM)</div>
```

Let say I need the "Dimensions" and Type.

code:

```
dts = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("dt");
for dt in dts :

    if dt.("innerText") == "Dimensions":
        print(dt.("innerText") + "-" + dt.**FollowingSibling**())
    if dt.("innerText") == "Type":
        print(dt.("innerText") + "-" + dt.**FollowingSibling**())
```

expected output:

```
Dimensions - 149.9 x 70.4 x 7.8 mm (5.90 x 2.77 x 0.31 in)
Type - Dynamic AMOLED capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `text` attribute or `innerText` as your wish.Try below code.

```
for dt in dts :

    if dt.text == "Dimensions":
        print(dt.text + "-" + dt.find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::div").text)
    if dt.text == "Type":
        print(dt.text + "-" + dt.find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::div").text)
```

OR

```
dts = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("dt");
for dt in dts :

    if dt.get_attribute("innerText")== "Dimensions":
        print(dt.get_attribute("innerText") + "-" + dt.find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::div").text)
    if dt.get_attribute("innerText") == "Type":
        print(dt.get_attribute("innerText") + "-" + dt.find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::div").text)
```

Output :

```
Dimensions-149.9 x 70.4 x 7.8 mm (5.90 x 2.77 x 0.31 in)
Type-Dynamic AMOLED capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code (finding elements by xpath):

```
dts = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("dt");
for dt in dts :

    if dt.("innerText") == "Dimensions":
        print(dt.("innerText") + "-" + dt.xpath("//div[contains(.,'Dimensions')]/following-sibling::div").text)
    if dt.("innerText") == "Type":
        print(dt.("innerText") + "-" + dt.xpath("//div[contains(.,'Type')]/following-sibling::div").text)
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding the following sibling of an element you can use the CSS selector or XPath. 
Using XPath you can find the sibling element without knowing/matching the locator of the previous element. 
But if you use CSS selectors, then you have to use the selector for the sibling element of the element.

**Xpath**

```py
dts = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("dt");
for dt in dts :

    if dt.text == "Dimensions":
        print(dt.text + "-" + dt.find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::div").text)
    if dt.text == "Type":
        print(dt.text + "-" + dt.find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::div").text)
```

**CSS Selector**

```py
dts = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("dt")
das = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".dt + div")
for i in range(0, len(dts) :
    if dt.index(i).text == "Dimensions":
        print(dt.indext(i).text + "-" + da.index(i).text)
    if dt.index(i).text == "Type":
        print(dt.index(i).text + "-" + da.index(i)..text)
```

CSS selector will only find the divs that followed a tag with dt class. It will work on your given scenario because all the divs with dt class followed by a div with da tag that contains the value.